# items_per_page.Error Description: 0

Tags: views

I have added two category of blogs and i want to show only one blogs of each category on front page. I found the option Home » Administer » Site building » Views.- Edit Block View.. When i change no of Items to display and save it showing error message.
 "admin/build/views/ajax/display/Block/block_2/items_per_page.Error Description: 0: "  Anyone knows about this.

Comment: Something wrong with your view? Export your view and send here and we will have a look into it..

Comment: i checked my view..anythin more about this issue...